# InDesign Server Crashing on Data Merge

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, mailmerge, indesign-server

I'm trying to do a very basic data merge with InDesign Server and keep getting a crash.
I begin the server with `./InDesignServer -port 18383` starts with no problems.
I call the script with `./sampleclient ./scripts/test.jsx`
The .jsx looks like this:

```js
var source = File("/Users/me/Desktop/InDesign Server/example/example.indd")
var destination = File("/Users/me/Desktop/InDesign Server/example/example.pdf")
var sourceData = File("/Users/me/Desktop/InDesign Server/example/example.csv")
var doc = app.open(source);

doc.dataMergeProperties.selectDataSource(sourceData);
doc.dataMergeProperties.dataMergePreferences.recordNumber = 1;
doc.dataMergeProperties.mergeRecords(); // <-- Crashes here

var myPDFExportPreset = app.pdfExportPresets.item(0);
app.documents.item(0).exportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, destination, false, myPDFExportPreset);
app.documents.item(0).close(SaveOptions.no);
doc.close(SaveOptions.no);
```

InDesign Server responds with:

```
Tue Sep 18 09:48:21 2018 INFO   [javascript] Executing Script
./InDesignServer: line 13: 30363 Segmentation fault: 11  "$installed_name" "$@"
```

And crashes. This script runs perfectly fine in InDesign CC Desktop. Server appears to crash on the .mergeRecords() call. Any ideas why?

Edit: I've modified the code to 1) Have no spaces in the file path 2) check that my objects all exist before performing the merge.

```js
var source = File("/Users/me/Desktop/example/example.indd");
var destination = File("/Users/me/Desktop/example/example.pdf");
var sourceData = File("/Users/me/Desktop/example/example.csv");

var doc = app.open(source);
doc.dataMergeProperties.selectDataSource(sourceData);

if (source.exists && destination.exists && sourceData.exists) {
    try {
        app.consoleout("Performing merge...");
        doc.dataMergeProperties.mergeRecords(); // <-- Crashes here
    } catch (err) {
        app.consoleout(err);
    }
} else {
    app.consoleout("Something doesn't exist...");
}
```

It logs "Performing merge..." so my file paths do in fact point to files that exist. What's more, it full on crashes, and does not report any errors.

Edit 2:
It should be noted, this is the error the Terminal window which launched sampleclient gets from IDS: `Error -1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]
"End of file or no input: Operation interrupted or timed out"
Detail: [no detail]`

Comment: Could be the problem in the file paths.  Test in the script if sourceData exists. I specify a full path on the server.

Comment: Check if you need to escape the space Character in your pathes. Check if all objects are valid before using them

Comment: The file paths are okay. First, I switched to HFS (not POSIX), still works in Desktop, still crashes Server. I put an if() in there, source.exists && destination.exists && sourceData.exists, and it passes those test, consoleouts "All files exist". @NicolaiKant How do you have your files situated, and what type of paths are you using?

Comment: try to include full path like "/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Desktop/example/example.indd". Also, try to data merge a small file, may be it times out on a large file

Comment: No dice. I added /Macintosh HD/ - it still works fine in Desktop, but crashes Server. I simply have a document with a single frame with 4 lines. A CSV just has 3 rows, 4 columns with some text. I've tested this on 3 different computers (3 separate installations), all with the same crash. A perplexing problem for 17 lines of code...

Comment: It should be noted, the error returned to Terminal from the window launching sampleclient : Error -1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]
"End of file or no input: Operation interrupted or timed out"
Detail: [no detail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folks at Adobe took notice, and fixed this issue for the 2019 release of InDesign Server. The same script, with a similar merging document, no longer produces the error.

So, for a solution, update to 2019.

More information:
[Adobe Forums Post](https://forums.adobe.com/message/10899612#10899612)

Comment: You may as well evaluate other products, cheaper than IDS yet really powerful for vdp and mailmerge. See Callas PDFChip for example.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, if others find themselves in my situation.
Still a mystery why mergeRecords() seems broken in Server.

```
doc.dataMergeProperties.exportFile()
```

Props to Colecandoo: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2478708

My code is now:

```js
var source = File("/Users/me/Desktop/example/example.indd");
var destination = File("/Users/me/Desktop/example/example.pdf");
var sourceData = File("Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:example:example.csv");

var doc = app.open(source);
var myExport = File(doc.filePath + "/" + doc.name.split(".indd")[0] + ".pdf");  
doc.dataMergeProperties.dataMergePreferences.recordNumber = 3;
with (doc.dataMergeProperties.dataMergePreferences) {
   recordSelection = RecordSelection.ONE_RECORD;    
            }
   app.dataMergeOptions.removeBlankLines = true;  
                doc.dataMergeProperties.exportFile(myExport, "[High Quality Print]", );
```

Still takes some tweaking, but it's performing the merge - this is what I needed.